# A valid database connection is required to run this generator in yii even if multiple database is configured

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have already configured main.php for handling more than one database then also gii gives error my main.php has following settings for connections

```
'db'=>array(
        'class' => 'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.DATABASENAME,
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => YII_DB_UNAME,
        'password' => YII_DB_PASS,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),

'db_transport'=>array(
        'class' => 'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.YII_TRANSPORT_DB,
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => YII_DB_UNAME,
        'password' => YII_DB_PASS,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),

'db_admission'=>array(
        'class' => 'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.YII_ADMISSION_DB,
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => YII_DB_UNAME,
        'password' => YII_DB_PASS,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),

'db_extendedsims'=>array(
        'class' => 'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.YII_EXTENDEDSIMS_DB,
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => YII_DB_UNAME,
        'password' => YII_DB_PASS,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

Now when i use GII and in Database Connection i write 'db' (without quotes) it works but if i write 'db_extendedsims' it doesn't work. what should i do to make it work for all connections

Comment: just comment other connections and use gii, when done, uncomment.

Comment: what is the error message? The others 'db_*' work?

Answer (score 0):

A much cooler way to use multiple db connection when using yii:

```
    'db' => array(
        'class' => 'PortalDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',
        'username' => 'dev',
        'password' => '123456',
        'tablePrefix' => '',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'enableParamLogging' => true,
        'enableProfiling' => true,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
    'dbx' => array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb1',
        'username' => 'dev',
        'password' => '123456',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => '',
        'autoConnect' => false,
        'class' => 'CDbConnection', //this may be the reason you get errors! always set this
    ),
```

and now, the php code for your model:

```
<?php

class DomainSlaveM extends Domain {

    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public static $server_id = 1;
    public static $slave_db;

    public function getDbConnection() {
        self::$slave_db = Yii::app()->dbx;
        if (self::$slave_db instanceof CDbConnection) {
            self::$slave_db->active = false;
            $config = require(Yii::app()->getBasePath() . '/config/main.php');
//set new connection string; also, you may set the right db user and pass if needed
                $connectionString = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb' . self::$server_id;
                self::$slave_db->connectionString = sprintf($connectionString, 'dbx');
                self::$slave_db->setActive(true);
                return self::$slave_db;
            }
            else
                throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii', 'Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
        }

    }
```

and use it like this:

```
    public function createDomainSlaveM($model) {
//switch the db connection; $server_id gets values, from 1 to N
            DomainSlaveM::$server_id = $model->user_id;
            $model_domain_slave_m = new DomainSlaveM();
            $model_domain_slave_m->attributes = $model->attributes;
            if ($model_domain_slave_m->validate() && $model_domain_slave_m->save()) {
                //ok
            } else {
                //bad
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My machine is x64,

I modify file C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini,  set mysql port from 3308 to 3306,that is work right!